# Change the default ASP.NET ClientIDMode at the project or solution level?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, web-config

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the default `ClientIDMode` for an entire project / solution / web deployment?

It would be nice not to have to change this on the few pages we actually use asp.net controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can [set ClientIDMode in web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/950xf363(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
<pages clientIDMode="[AutoID|Predictable|Static]" />
```